# what is a significance of "Java 2" in J2EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Why J2EE why not J7EE or J8EE . We got latest version as Java 8. But, why still, it is being Java Platform 2 ? What is a significance of "2" here ? Or It looks good, that's why they never changed its name or some other reason ?

Comment: It is `JavaEE` first of all. That J2EE naming was earlier convention.

Comment: @shekharsuman the number always signify version in software AFAIK. If it was earlier convention then It should change, because we are not using earlier version now. right ?

Answer (score 4):

Java enterprise edition was introduced around the time of Java 2 (which was rebranded from Java 1.2). As part of the branding they included the numeral (originally). Now it is officially [Java EE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/index.html) (withtout the numeral 2).

Comment: [Sun](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems) was always much better at engineering than branding and marketing.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [Version History of Java EE in Wikipedia's content on Java Platform, Enterprise Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Version_history) :-

> The platform **was** known as *Java 2 Platform, Enterprise Edition or J2EE*
>   until the name was changed to **Java Platform, Enterprise Edition** or
>   Java EE in version 5. The current version is called ***Java EE 7***.

Also to add the details of all versions :-

1. J2EE 1.2 (December 12, 1999)
2. J2EE 1.3 (September 24, 2001)
3. J2EE 1.4 (November 11, 2003)
4. Java EE 5 (May 11, 2006)
5. Java EE 6 (December 10, 2009)
6. Java EE 7 (May 28, 2013, but April 5, 2013 according to spec document. June 12, 2013 was the planned kickoff date)
7. Java EE 8 (expected around Q3 2016)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good explanation of that in the link below :
[[Java EE vs J2EE vs Jakarta EE]](https://www.baeldung.com/java-enterprise-evolution)

***For J2EE :***

In the first version of Java, Java enterprise extensions were simply a part of the core JDK.

Then, as part of Java 2 in 1999, these extensions were broken out of the standard binaries, and J2EE, or Java 2 Platform Enterprise Edition, was born. It would keep that name until 2006.

For Java 5 in 2006, J2EE was renamed to Java EE or Java Platform Enterprise Edition. That name would stick all the way to September 2017.

Answer (score -1):

Current java is known as Java 2 Platform.

Originally there was JDK1.0 and JDK1.1. They are not compatible to current Java platform. With release of JDK1.2, Java 2 Platform have been born.

> Release 1.4 of the Java 2 Platform, Standard Edition (J2SE) represents an advance from J2SE 1.3

[More On](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-jsp-138567.html)

Comment: This is just not true.  The current version of Java is absolutely NOT known as Java 2 Platform.